# I can't submit data into database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I am new to Larave and using Laravel Framework 6.17.1. I am getting this error when submitting data to the database using the form. Bellow is the error I am getting.

Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Header, 2020-03-27 07:55:06, 2020-03-27 07:55:06))

**PostContolller.php**

```
 public function create()
{
    //
    return view('posts.create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    //return $request->all();
    Post::create($request->all());
}
```

**Table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Route**

Route::resource('/posts', 'PostController');

Comment: If you `dd($request->all())` you will see that there is no `user_id` key. That needs to be supplied, because you have not made that column `nullable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error it's because the user_id column is not nullable. To solve the issues ensure the following:

1) In Post Model add the following fillable:

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'title', 'content'];
```

3) In your PostController.php, you must have the following constructor. To ensure the only user who is authenticated can create a post.

```
 public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

2) I am assuming that the user submitting the form is an authenticated user in your application. Hence, in the blade where you have your form add the following line of code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
```

In the above piece of code, we are passing a hidden filled which contains your user_id value which gets from Laravel Auth facade.

Now when you `dd($request->all());` you should be able to see **user_id** in your array.

NB: When using mass assignment you need to add protected fillable on your model and ensure the name you use in input filled to match the exact name in your model. [Learn more about Laravel mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Answer (score 1):

Just put in your Post model, whenever you use `create` method make sure your all columns as a `fillable` property put in your model.

**Post.php**

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $fillable = ['user_id','title','content'];
}
```

In your controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $request['user_id'] = $id;
    Post::create($request->all());
}
```

Comment: please mark as verified this answer. if its help to you Thank you@Ihtisham Khan

Comment: please select my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending user_id in form submit from blade file i.e $request->all() doesn't contain `user_id`

If `user_id` is not mandatory then add `$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();` in migration file

Comment: I got the idea, Thank you 